# Get URL data from java app

Tags: java

i need get data from this url:

"https://demanda.ree.es/movil/peninsula/demanda/tablas/2015-02-19/2"

But the data that I read is the html structure without any data.

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

things I've tried

Read with URLConnection, ApiWeb, jsoup, commons-io

Comment: How are you reading the data?  If you don't show us what you're doing, it's hard to guess what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Physically get data that is appended to the URL or Data from the page itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page use `jQuery`, so downloading the html will not give you the data.., it need to complie the javascript to loaded the data.

But your best oppurtunity to *steal* this data is to study `jquery` and call the `jquery` results directly.

For example look what this does... [Stealing some of it](https://demanda.ree.es/WSvisionaMovilesPeninsulaRest/resources/demandaInstantanea), its also in a great format `json` that can be easily parsed by libs

Comment: How did you do that ??

Comment: I did some study of the javascript core.min.js to see what is was calling to fill the table

Comment: Yes, but I did not find any method to get the data to a specific date

Comment: They pass the date as parameter GET /WSvisionaMovilesPeninsulaRest/resources/maxMinPeninsula?callback=angular.callbacks._0&curva=DEMANDA&fecha=2015-02-19

Comment: WSvisionaMovilesPeninsulaRest/resources/prevProgPeninsula?callback=angular.callbacks._1&curva=DEMANDA&fecha=2015-02-19

Comment: WSvisionaMovilesPeninsulaRest/resources/demandaGeneracionPeninsula?callback=angular.callbacks._2&curva=DEMANDA&fecha=2015-02-19

Comment: WSvisionaMovilesPeninsulaRest/resources/coeficientesCO2?callback=angular.callbacks._3&curva=DEMANDA&fecha=2015-02-19&mapId2=Peninsula

Comment: Consider accepting the answer...

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but I think I can start working on it. Thank you very much, I love you ;-)

Comment: I hope you are female ; )